# run a code block in php foreach even when foreach array is empty

Tags: php

I have a dynamic form which does insert and update at the same time. This is working well for updating existing data but it is not working when inserting data, that is because `$input_fields` is empty so the `foreach` throws an error and form fields won't show. so how do I run the code inside the `foreach` when `$input_fields` is empty?

```
   <?php foreach ($input_fields as $input_field) : ?>
            // some demo code below
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Name</label>
                <input class="form-control field_name_input name" type="text" name="data[][name]" value="<?= $input_field['name'] ?>">
            </div>
            // some demo code below ends
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I tried below code before `foreach`

```
if(!$input_fields) {
    $input_fields = [];
};
```

and below code in `foreach`

```
foreach ((array)$input_fields as $input_field)
```

but that doesn't help as first code snippet is just empty array so the loop won't happen and second one is almost same thing. I hope you understand.

> **EDIT 1: $input_fields is an array where I saved form attributes.**

Comment: What will you want to paste in `$input_fields[]` when it is empty? I suggest you don't wrap the html content / layout such as `<div></div>` in your php, especially it is in your for-loop!!!

Comment: Your input is empty ... it wouldnt make sense to run then a foreach over it, cause there is no "each".

Comment: the form fields. just the form value attributes will be empty.

Comment: the question is: Why is your $input_fields empty when inserting new data? Why don't you insert a new element before?

Comment: $input_fields is an array where I saved form attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so, I added this lines of code before `foreach` and It's working as I
>   expected

```
if(empty($input_fields)) {
    $input_fields = [[]];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an empty default array use a default entry:

```
if(!is_array($input_fields) || empty($input_fields)) {
    $input_fields = [
        [
            'name' => "Hubba Bubba"
            // and some more elements
        ]
    ];
};
```

Comment: Could even put the default value blank ( 'name' => '' ) since that seems to be what he wants (based on comments) in case of empty array.

Comment: @Aurelien Whatever, sure. but the more important details you pushed me towards is that the OP requires an array as element inside the outer array. so: thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your if doesn't work because you are asking if the array is empty and then assigning it empty.

Instead of doing that you could surround your foreach loop inside the if that checks if it is empty
Then it will only run if size >=1

If you want to run the loop at least once you could and empty default value or you could write the html tags inside your if block